# Storing a reference in a struct

Tags: struct, rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to build a wrapper struct around the gnuplot lib for Rust.

I want to plot multiple sets of lines in the same 2D-axes object, therefore I need to keep the `Axes2D` around.

How can I fix this structure? The `figure` and the `axes` fields will live exactly as long as the `plot` struct itself.

```
use gnuplot::{Axes2D, Figure, Caption, Color};

pub struct Plot {
    figure: Figure,
    axes: &mut Axes2D,
}

impl Plot {
    pub fn new() -> Plot {
        let fig = Figure::new();
        Plot {
            figure: fig,
            axes: fig.axes2d(),
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with the following compiler error:

```
plot.rs:6:11: 6:22 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
plot.rs:6     axes: &mut Axes2D,
```

I've tried adding lifetime `'a` at the struct, field and impl, but this gives me different errors. Since I'm not sure what I'm doing, I was wondering if someone could explain how to achieve this.

Comment: I think that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct will answer your question.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks. I did try google before I posted this btw. :)

Comment: No worries, it's a common problem and why that question was created. Hopefully, we will be able to mark a bunch of things as duplicates to make the SEO way better. :-)

Comment: Do you suggest using the owing_ref here, or is there a more idiomatic way to handle this?

Comment: It looks like having multiple structs is more appropriate.

Comment: Putting the Axes2D in its own struct? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88388/discussion-between-jesse-and-shepmaster).